# What should go in the different projects in a SL/XNA solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xna

In Visual Studio 2010 I created a new Windows Phone Silverlight and XNA Application. The solution it created contained 3 projects:

1. myProject
2. myProjectLib
3. myProjectLibContent

I can understand that content like pictures and textures, should go in myProjectLibContent, but what about myProjectLib, what should I put in there instead of in a folder in myProject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the projects are set up like that is simply a quirk of how Visual Studio and XNA Game Studio work.

So you start with `myProject` which is a Silverlight project. It's the same as any Silverlight project you'd create - except that it also has assembly references to the XNA assemblies so you can write XNA code within this project and it will compile just fine.

Now, because you're using XNA, you probably want to use the XNA content pipeline. So you get an XNA Content Pipeline project (`myProjectLibContent`) in the template as well.

Now all you have to do is build these two projects, right? Wrong!

First of all, an XNA Content Pipeline project is a special kind of project. It can't build itself - try it - try right-clicking the project and selecting "Build" - the option isn't there.

**An XNA Content Pipeline project can only be built from an XNA project. The Silverlight project is *not* an XNA project.** Only XNA projects can have "Content References" - which the XNA project will then build during its own build. Note the Silverlight project doesn't have a "Content References" section.

So the ***only*** reason that the XNA Library Project `myProjectLib` exists is to act as a bridge between the Silverlight project and the content project. The Silverlight project references the XNA Library project, which in turn builds and includes the content project.

This means that you can safely ignore the XNA Library project and leave it empty.

It's the same deal on Windows. A WinForms project that uses XNA needs an XNA Library project in order to build XNA content projects.

Answer (score 2):

Lib is a "Library" project. Usually one is *not* created when creating a XNA game, even in 4.0. In fact, you don't have to put anything in it in the one it created for you.

Typically, a Library is a storage of centralized routines one would use on *any* game or *any game of your game's type* (like *any rpg*). And then you would call those routines from the more specific implementations in the game's base project library.

However, none of that's required and if this is your first game, I'd recommend you ignore in entirely. Place your code in the first project, the content in the 3rd and go to town!